# Placeholder variable type

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I need to get information from a class function. Said class has overloaded operators for basically any standard type. Therefore

```cpp
double foo = exampleObject.getInformation();
```

and

```cpp
std::string faa = exampleObject.getInformation();
```

Would both work. If the information can not be transformed into a double, foo will be set to 0. The initialization of faa will always work. (It can always be expressed as a string)

My problem is: I want to get the information and save it as a double variable, if that can not be done as the information is not of numeric type, I want the variable to be a string. I basically need a variable that can change its type. How do I do this? I'm sorry if that is a very basic question, C++ is not my main programming language.

Comment: How do you tell if the returned value is convertible to `double` or not?

Comment: `std::variant` can do it.  Or `std::any`.

Comment: C++ is a typed language (presumably, unlike your "main programming language") so a variable's type cannot change dynamically. Function overloading is also based on types of a function's arguments, not its return type. There is no way in C++ to do what you want, without giving information at the call point that allows the compiler to work out the return type of the function overload being called.  (`std::any` is a little different, but still requires valid type information to be supplied, otherwise an exception is thrown at run time).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Function Templates?
They won't change the type of a variable but will allow you to write your code in a way that works with more than 1 data type.

If c++ is not your main, I would recommend checking the checking the documentation for Function Templates on cplusplus.com

Here => https://cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

Comment: I already checked out templates. Problem is: I get the function from a library therefore can't change the return type of the class member functions.

Comment: I have an idea...

Comment: I have an idea...
Maybe you could get the info always as a string and write a function to check if its content can be converted to double, or not, if it can, then it gets converted and stored to a double variable. If it doesn't, you leave it as a string. That same check could be used to generate an indicator if your code should be using the double or string variables.